# Why doesn't Loki revert to his true form while in the TVA?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki

In *Loki* episode 1, it is said that:

> Magic powers? They're no good in the TVA, Mr. Laufeyson.

How come Loki is in human form throughout his time in the TVA, then, as he is actually (genetically) a Frost Giant?

Comment: Related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/15069/46980

Comment: @F1Krazy this is talking about *Thor 1*, not *Loki*...

Comment: I know, that's why I said it's related, not a duplicate. It explains why Loki looks like a human most of the time, but doesn't explain why he still looks like a human in the TVA.

Answer (score 2):

During the time of adoption, Odin changed Loki's look entirely to look more like an Asgardian rather than a Frost Giant by touching him.

Although Loki still can return back to his Frost Giant look, if he gets the freezing touch from other Frost Giants.

Comment: But this is *magic* that makes him look like this, no? And all magic is prohibited in the TVA...

Comment: You are exactly right @taylor.2317